# Timestamp to date with Javascript. How?

Tags: php, javascript

I create a timestamp with strtotime php function. My question is how to "reverse" timestamp to year, month, date, ... seconds etc using javascript ?

Comment: Reference: [PHP date functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

Comment: Reference: [PHP date functions (new, improved OOP way)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a php timestamp to the same format as new Date() in javaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415877/how-can-i-convert-a-php-timestamp-to-the-same-format-as-new-date-in-javascript) | also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date(phptimestamp*1000);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(seconds*1000);
```

where milliseconds is seconds since Jan 1970.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(timestamp*1000);
```